# Обработка формы input на Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Есть форма на странице - http://biborus.pythonanywhere.com/
Необходимо с помощью Flask получить запрос из формы, и отдать пользователю ту-же страницу + информацию по обработанному запросу. Например, кол-во символов в запросе.
Как это реализовывается?

Comment: В документации неплохо описано с примерами [The Request Object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#the-request-object)

Answer (score 2):

Можно реализовать с помощью модулей `re` и `requests`

```
import re
import requests

test = requests.get('http://site.com')
form_pars = re.findall(r'<input.*', test.text)  # Это регулярное выражение только для '<input' формы
print(form_pars)
```

Далее получаете ключи и отправляете соответствующие запросы гет или пост с необходимыми параметрами, посмотрите в сторону библеотек для парсинга сайтов. Примеров как сделать веб интерфейс на `Flask` достаточно много